# Shared Memory Provider MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

MSSQL 2017, windows server 2016

Имеется запрос вида:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (...),

EFPurchaseList ( purchaseNum ) as (
SELECT DISTINCT
    table.fst.value('(...) [1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
FROM table
    CROSS APPLY table.fst.nodes('.../.[1]') nodes(setting)
WHERE nodes.setting.value('(...) [1]', 'nvarchar(max)') = 'value'),

ApplicationList (purchaseNum,   lotNum, journalNum, participantType, inn, kpp, orgn, idNumber, countryCode, countryFullName, [status]) as (
SELECT DISTINCT
    secondTable.fst.value('(...) [1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
    '1',
    nodes.setting.value('(...) [1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
    nodes.setting.value('(...) [1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
    nodes.setting.value('(...) [1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
    nodes.setting.value('(...) [1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
    nodes.setting.value('(...) [1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
    nodes.setting.value('(...) [1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
    nodes.setting.value('(...) [1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
    nodes.setting.value('(...) [1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
    nodes.setting.value('(...) [1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
FROM secondTable
CROSS APPLY secondTable.fst.nodes('.../.[1]') nodes(setting)
),

suppliersList (purchaseNumber, lotNum, journalNum, participantType, inn, kpp, ogrn, idNumber, countryCode, countryFullName, [status], pN) as (
SELECT *
FROM ApplicationList INNER JOIN EFPurchaseList on EFPurchaseList.purchaseNum = ApplicationList.purchaseNum)

SELECT suppliersList.inn, count(suppliersList.inn) FROm suppliersList GROUP BY suppliersList.inn
```

*Уточнение - `...` написано за место пути.*

В процессе выполнения запроса вылезает ошибка:

> Сообщение 109, уровень 20, состояние 0, строка 0
>   Ошибка на транспортном уровне при получении результатов с сервера. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - Канал был закрыт.)

Судя по файлам трассировки, достаточно часто случаются циклы `Audit logout` и `Audit login`

Последняя часть лога перед ошибкой (картинка):

[image: Финальная часть лога]

Не знаю, как лучше приложить файл лога, если это, конечно, нужно.

Как избавиться от данной ошибки и из-за чего она происходит?

Comment: А запрос выполняется локально на сервере? Какие сетевые протоколы разрешены, точнее разрешен ли протокол TCP/IP?